# Upload an image in lwc rich text component doesn't work

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightninginput

I'm using a `lightning-input-rich-tex` base component and I'm trying to upload an image but it doesn't work

[image]
Code

```
<lightning-input-rich-text
                        formats={formats}
                        data-id="rich-text"
                        label={label.Description}
                        placeholder={label.Description_placeholder}
                        valid={isDescriptionValid}
></lightning-input-rich-text>
```

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-rich-text/documentation) it's not clear but the `share-with-entity-id` attribute needs to be populated with a valid record id. Then salesforce will create a file shared with that record.